# Impact of refresh_interval on ElasticSearch on old non-changing indices

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been reading [several](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html) [articles](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings), [both](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html) [elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/translog.html).co as well [from](https://qbox.io/blog/maximize-guide-elasticsearch-indexing-performance-part-1) [blogs](https://sematext.com/blog/elasticsearch-refresh-interval-vs-indexing-performance/), but I do not manage to get a clear understanding of what is happening with `refresh_interval`.

Does the `refresh_interval` have an impact of the systems performance and resource consumption when an index is not changing?

Does it make sense to increase the `refresh_interval` for older indices that won't change, to obtain a better performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36456615/7983309) answer will help clarify and better your understanding of how refresh works

Also, though I was fairly confident of the answer myself I went ahead and asked on Elastic discussion forum anyway https://discuss.elastic.co/t/refresh-interval-setting-on-old-indices/154075 so to answer your question, its unlikely performance will be improved